# Refreshing service references updates the app.config

Tags: .net, app-config, service-reference

Every time I make changes to my WS and update the reference in Visual Studio, VS overwrites my app.config with additional unnecessary information.  So when I start my client afterwards, I get this error:

> An error was discovered processing the  header

The changes that the code generator made was to **remove** this line from every binding (note I'm using customBinding/httpsTransport):

```
<security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" includeTimestamp="false">
    <secureConversationBootstrap/>
</security>
```

Then I have to close the client, revert the app.config changes and restart the client which is a hassle.

I would prefer if the app.config would be left alone.

Are you experiencing the same problem and do you have a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing this programmatically which solved the problem.

Comment: Can you please give a brief description of how you got around this issue? Using ChannelFactory<T>? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stop changing your WS!?! :P

Seriously though, since you are updating your WS and then updating the reference it is going to update the app.config / web.config. The reason is because there is a section under applicationSettings that reference the WS.

EX:

```
 <applicationSettings>
    <RemoteAssessment.CatCall.My.MySettings>
        <setting name="RemoteAssessment_CatCall_CATService01_CATService"
            serializeAs="String">
            <value>URLTOSERVICE/catservice.asmx</value>
        </setting>
    </RemoteAssessment.CatCall.My.MySettings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Sadly, I do not think there is a way to stop VS from updating the app.config.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't have that applicationSettings section within my app.config. (might be a VB.NET thing?).  I do have an endpoint section that refers to the service though

Comment: It was just an example to go with what I was saying about the app.config references the WS.