# How can I prevent VS2010 to create a new binding each time I update a service reference?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, app-config, wcf-binding

I'm developing a Winforms Client application with a WCF Service in C # 3.5 and Visual Studio 2010.

Every time I use "*Update Service Reference*" in the IDE, considering I have already a working binding in `app.config`, an additional binding entry is generated with the same name and a trailing "1".

My app.config on the client side is :

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
     <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IIssueTracker" closeTimeout="00:01:00"...
```

After a "Update Service Reference", I have :

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
     <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IIssueTracker" closeTimeout="00:01:00"...
     <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IIssueTracker1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"...
```

So I need to remove this unused binding all the time.

This is driving me nut. Is there a way to disable this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we solved this was to move the Service Reference to a separate library, and delete the (newly generated) app.config from the library project after executing Update Service Reference.

Comment: I tried this: it works very well. I have even the feeling that my project structure looks cleaner. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I normally just revert any changes to the app.config (using SVN)... that works equally well and doesn't require another project.  I had the same question here, but it's not really resolved to my liking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625743/refreshing-service-references-updates-the-app-config