# The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded

Tags: wcf, basichttpbinding

I get this exception while creating scope for few tables all those tables are huge in design

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding_ISyncServices" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
            openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
            transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                enabled="false" />
            <security mode="Message">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"
                    proxyCredentialType="None" realm="">
                    <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
                </transport>
                <message clientCredentialType="Windows"
                    negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I have made `MaxReceivedMessageSize` to 2147483647
but still it is giving me below exception at this line

```
 client.GetTableDescription(scopeName, syncTable)
```

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded.
>   To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF - How to Increase Message Size Quota](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF - How to Increase Message Size Quota](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota)

Answer (score 124):

As per [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota)

> You will want something like this:
>
> ```
> <bindings>
>      <basicHttpBinding>
>          <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
>  maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
>  maxBufferSize="20000000"
>  maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
>              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
>  maxArrayLength="200000000"
>  maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
>          </binding>
>      </basicHttpBinding> </bindings>
> ```

Please also read comments to the accepted answer there, those contain valuable input.

Answer (score 29):

If you are using CustomBinding then you would rather need to make changes in httptransport element.
Set it as

```xml
 <customBinding>
    <binding ...>
     ...
     <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
 </customBinding>
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 100X. I wonder how many hours of my life WCF configuration has wasted.

Comment: yep, you saved me a ton of hours too

Comment: I'm another very happy person after working on this error for two weeks.  We had a BizTalk WCF Custom Behavior in C# that needed the binding-template.xml updated with this.

Comment: Seriously, I would be a happy man if I could recover all the hours I've spent swearing at WCF configurations. But this was the right answer for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Updating the config didn't work for me, but I was able to edit the binding programmatically:

```cs
private YourAPIClient GetClient()
{
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri(APIURL);

    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20000000;
    binding.MaxBufferSize = 20000000;
    binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 20000000;
    binding.AllowCookies = true;

    var readerQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
    readerQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 20000000;
    readerQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 20000000;
    readerQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
    binding.ReaderQuotas = readerQuotas;

    if (baseAddress.Scheme.ToLower() == "https")
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

    var client = new YourAPIClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
    return client;
}
```

Comment: on which part of the WCF service did you place this?

Comment: @Malky.Kid i created this client to call a .net based soap web service.

Answer (score 15):

You need to make the changes in the binding configuration (in the app.config file) on the SERVER and the CLIENT, or it will not take effect.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647 " max...=... />
        </basicHttpBinding>
       </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: But it's true. I've had the same problem, until I've changed setting on the client. Then it was OK.

Comment: If anyone will have similar problem. I've set everything up on the WCF, but  I was still receiving error message. On the client I've added code below and after that, it was OK. Thanks a lot @CarrieKendall.  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISotechWcfForWebService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

Comment: Same settings on server side with code: BasicHttpBinding bind01 = new BasicHttpBinding();bind01.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
bind01.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;bind01.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
bind01.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;bind01.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
bind01.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;bind01.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
bind01.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;bind01.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);

Comment: Adding  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647 " on the client side fixed my problem. Thank you

Comment: I created a simple webservice which returns a whole lot of records, and was getting this error. I tried applying the solution on the server, but that did not work, so I did as suggested, and changed WCF Test Client's config, and that did it. Instead of laughing, I tried it out. Just a thought

Comment: Thanks! I found the comment from @CarrieKendall a bit rude, but yours and the others made up for it :)

Answer (score 12):

You also need to increase [maxBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httptransportbindingelement.maxbuffersize.aspx).  Also note that you might need to increase the [readerQuotas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.readerquotas.aspx).

Comment: Why is visual studio marking 'maxBufferSize' as non-allowed ? I have VS 2010.

Comment: For future visitors: `maxBufferSize` must match `maxReceivedMessageSize`, otherwise it might throw an error.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
 Dim binding As New WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport)
 binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None
 binding.MaxBufferSize = Integer.MaxValue
 binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Integer.MaxValue
 binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = Integer.MaxValue
```

Comment: where id you place this? on the class?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the settings in `web.config` / `app.config` were ignored. I ended up creating my binding manually, which solved the issue for me:

```
var httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding()
{
    MaxBufferPoolSize = Int32.MaxValue,
    MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue,
    ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
    {
        MaxArrayLength = 200000000,
        MaxDepth = 32,
        MaxStringContentLength = 200000000
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the "-OutBuffer 2147483647" parameter in my query, which is part of the Common Parameters.
PS C:> Get-Help about_CommonParameters -Full