# how to increase MaxReceivedMessageSize when calling a WCF from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459697/the-maximum-message-size-quota-for-incoming-messages-65536-has-been-exceeded)

I am using WCF for file uploading and downloading. uploading is successful but when i downloading a large file i found this error

> Error : The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536)
>   has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the
>   MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

My Service.config file has the following code.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="4800" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />


  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"  />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <!--<webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
      </webHttpBinding>-->
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WITSService.WITSService">
        <clear />
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WITSService.WITSService" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myEndPointBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

can any one help me how to increase MaxReceivedMessageSize

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Change the customBinding in the web.config to use larger defaults. I picked 2MB as it is a reasonable size. Of course setting it to 2GB (as your code suggests) will work but it does leave you more vulnerable to attacks. Pick a size that is larger than your largest request but isn't overly large.

Check this : [Using Large Message Requests in Silverlight with WCF](http://wildermuth.com/2009/09/10/Using_Large_Message_Requests_in_Silverlight_with_WCF)

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior name="TestLargeWCF.Web.MyServiceBehavior">
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
       </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <bindings>
     <customBinding>
       <binding name="customBinding0">
         <binaryMessageEncoding />
         <!-- Start change -->
         <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152"
                        maxBufferSize="2097152"
                        maxBufferPoolSize="2097152"/>
         <!-- Stop change -->
       </binding>
     </customBinding>
   </bindings>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
   <services>
     <service behaviorConfiguration="Web.MyServiceBehavior" name="TestLargeWCF.Web.MyService">
       <endpoint address=""
                binding="customBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="customBinding0"
                contract="TestLargeWCF.Web.MyService"/>
       <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
     </service>
   </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to set [basicHttpBinding -> MaxReceivedMessageSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.httpbindingbase.maxreceivedmessagesize.aspx) in the client configuration.