# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request in WCF configuration

Tags: wcf

I have WCF hosted under website application at IIS. Below is service declarations in web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
<service  name="Emp.Depart.Handle">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="HandleBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IHandle"
           contract="Emp.Depart.IHandle" />
      </service>
    </services>
<behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
<behavior name="HandleBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="HandleBehaviors">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IHandle" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
              openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
              allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
              maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
              transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
              <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                  realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
            </binding>
     </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Despite of the previous declarations i got the error :

WCF The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request

when trying to connect from client, cofig of client is as follows :

```
<basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Ihl7" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483646" maxStringContentLength="2147483646" maxArrayLength="2147483646"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483646" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483646" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
```

I can't identify the cause of the problem, i searched and increased maxRecievedMessage but nothing happened.

Please advice.

Comment: you can enable wcf tracing to get more information. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: I cant see "address" in your endpoint...

Comment: 400 is a tricky one to pin down, it could be a number of things. The remote server is receiving the request, it just cannot determine what it is meant to do with it. Are you serializing objects and sending them over the wire? Try seeing exactly what you are calling, using Tracing as above, Fiddler etc.

Comment: I enabled WCF tracing but i can't extract anything from output!! how can i get the cause of the error? The client is calling method in the service expecting 2 string parameters, the client is sending data 1.5 MB to the method

Comment: I found the following exception message :
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Comment: how can i solve this issue please??
@mehdi.loa
Karthik Ganesan

Comment: @ barrick please advice

Comment: @Ahmy what is address set to in endpoint ? did you try to run just the service?

Comment: @Ahmy in your server side config file try to set
<binding maxReceivedMessageSize="524288000" messageEncoding="Mtom"> <!--500MB-->
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="1572864"/><!--1.5MB-->
        </binding>

Comment: @Ahmy: Add more detail in your question  your calling method + where are you getting this Exception " The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded"

Answer (score 0):

not nice and also strange way, but removing the name of the configuration may work bases on: [WCF service maxReceivedMessageSize basicHttpBinding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068612/wcf-service-maxreceivedmessagesize-basichttpbinding-issue)

also these could be useful:
[how to increase MaxReceivedMessageSize when calling a WCF from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134107/how-to-increase-maxreceivedmessagesize-when-calling-a-wcf-from-c-sharp)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358768.aspx/