# Request Entity Too Large I've tried everything

Tags: wcf, basichttpbinding

I've searched this and tried everything that SO has to offer. I've been at this for quite some time and I cannot find in my web.config what is wrong. I'm getting the message `"The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large."`

I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong! Help!

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

    <system.web>
      <compilation targetFramework="4.6" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>
          <add name="DefaultCache" duration="60" varyByParam="none" />
        </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
      <security>
          <requestFiltering>
              <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3521478366" />
          </requestFiltering>
      </security>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>

        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" allowCookies="true"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                     maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                     maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                              maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                              maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>

        <service name="TruckService.TruckService">
        <endpoint 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" 
            contract="TruckService.ITruckService">
            <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" showFlags="Date, Time, Size, Extension" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>

        <!-- removed for security purposes -->

  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

What I've tried:

[how to increase MaxReceivedMessageSize when calling a WCF from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134107/how-to-increase-maxreceivedmessagesize-when-calling-a-wcf-from-c-sharp)

[The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459697/the-maximum-message-size-quota-for-incoming-messages-65536-has-been-exceeded)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to keep the file transfer format of the server-side and the client-side the same. Deviation may cause this problem.

In addition, on the premise that increasing the message size and buffer size does not work, you can try to change a value: `maxitemsinobjectgraph` like this:

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1365536" />
    </behavior>
 </behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1365536" />
    </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I made the change to match what you posted and it didn't have any effect. I am getting `The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.`

Comment: Is the problem solved? Is there any other error message according to the method.