# Error: the maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded

Tags: wcf

I get this error message

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded

when I try to upload files(+-160KB) to my WCF service. I've tried to increase the values of the following attributes :

```
maxReceivedMessageSize,
maxBufferPoolSize,
maxArrayLength,
maxStringContentLength,
```

but I had no luck. My WCF config file looks like this :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="3200000" maxBufferPoolSize="100000000"  >
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="1000000000" maxStringContentLength="3200000" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="PMSService.Thomolosha"
        name="PMSService.Thomolosha" >
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"  contract="PMSService.ThomoloshaDeclaration">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="PMSService.Arekwe"
              name="PMSService.Arekwe">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="PMSService.ArekweDeclaration">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="PMSService.Thomolosha">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="PMSService.Arekwe">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

My Winform config looks like this :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ThomoloshaDeclaration" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="100000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="3200000" messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="3200000" maxArrayLength="1000000000"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
              algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ArekweDeclaration" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="100000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="3200000" messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="3200000" maxArrayLength="1000000000"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
              algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:57388/Thomolosha.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ThomoloshaDeclaration" contract="Thomolosha.ThomoloshaDeclaration"
        name="WSHttpBinding_ThomoloshaDeclaration">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:57388/Arekwe.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ArekweDeclaration" contract="Arekwe.ArekweDeclaration"
        name="WSHttpBinding_ArekweDeclaration">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459697/the-maximum-message-size-quota-for-incoming-messages-65536-has-been-exceeded)

Comment: In the code are you sure you're using the correct binding?

Comment: @GarrettVlieger duplicate how ?

Comment: @Aelphaeis yes, it works fine with small files.

Comment: @chosenOneThabs, this is the same question as one that's already been answered. Follow the link to see a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: @GarrettVlieger yes i have tried most of those solutions but no luck. Most people suspect these attributes : maxReceivedMessageSize,
maxBufferPoolSize,maxArrayLength,maxStringContentLength. I've fiddle around with these attributes but i had no luck. That's why i decided to paste my configs in this block.

Comment: @chosenOneThabs if you follow the 'possible duplicate of' questions all the way back you'll find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9018218/97614) which shows the named config being applied.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF - How to Increase Message Size Quota](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're getting the error on the service side (when you try to upload).  According to your posted service config, you've set a higher limit for `maxReceivedMessageSize` and other settings, but you never **assign** that binding to your service endpoint(s), so WCF is using the default value for `maxReceivedMessageSize` (65536).

You need to assign your defined binding (`wsBinding`) to your service endpoint(s) via the `bindingConfiguration` attribute of the `endpoint` element, like this:

```
<endpoint address="" 
          binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingCongifuration="wsBinding"
          contract="PMSService.ThomoloshaDeclaration">
```

Now the service will use the binding configuration you've defined, that has the larger size.

Comment: @chosenOneThabs: If this answer did solve your problem as you have indicated, then please mark it as such. This may help guide programmers to the answer in the future when trying to solve this problem.