# "The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded" error

Tags: web-services, wcf

I know there are several posts like this.
I didn't forget to match the binding name with the bindingConfiguration of the endpoint.
I already set the properties      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647".
I keep getting the same message (I don't know if it is a default message or nothing is updating the 65536 value).

The web service I am connecting doesn't belong to me, but I can call to the same method using SoapUI succesfully.

This is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://domain/service.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding1"
        contract="SVC.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459697/the-maximum-message-size-quota-for-incoming-messages-65536-has-been-exceeded?rq=1, try to change the maxbufferpoolsize/maxArrayLength to 2147483647.

Comment: Ok, that was fast.
And worked.
Thank you, man!