# Despite changing "MaxReceivedMessageSize" but I still getting the error "System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I'm working on a web service, and when I send a query I can never get a response. The errors are:

--

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 'The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.'
>
> QuotaExceededException: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

--

But my "maxReceivedMessageSize" is 2147483647. I dont know what to do.

I increased the number 65536 to 2147483647.

//My App.config

```
<binding name="soapName" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                     receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="true"
                     bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                     maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                     textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                     messageEncoding="Text">
       <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
           maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
       <security mode="Transport" />
     </binding>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459697/the-maximum-message-size-quota-for-incoming-messages-65536-has-been-exceeded
?

Comment: Yes, its look like duplicate. But you can see my code. "maxReceivedMessageSize" is 2147483647. But program still stoping

Comment: Are you creating the WCF endpoint in code directly? Or using an endpoint/contract in config?

Comment: Binding properties and enpoint in my App.config. Andpoint is like; <endpoint address="xxxx"
    behaviorConfiguration="ClientCert" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="contextSoap12Binding"
    contract="VekaletnameListeSorgula.VekaletnameSorgu" name="contextHttpsSoap12Endpoint" />

Comment: And when i add my wsdl file, studio create a .svcinfo file