# Error:The Maximum message size quota for incoming messages

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

`The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.`

I have mentioned value in proxy. Do I need to mention in server side WCF Web.Config. If yes then may I know how?

My WCF Web.Config is mentioned below.

```
<binding name="NewBinding0" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">                
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
  <reliableSession enabled="true" />
    <security mode="None">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="false" />
    </security>
  </binding>
```

My Client side coding.

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
//binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 10485760;
//binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760;
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
//binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = true;
binding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20000000;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
//EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity("user@domain");
ChannelFactory<IDBSyncContract> factory = new ChannelFactory<IDBSyncContract>(binding, new EndpointAddress(endPointURL));
dbProxy = factory.CreateChannel();
this.dbProxy = dbProxy as IDBSyncContract;
```

Comment: did you refer this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota

Comment: My Server Side Web.Config<wsHttpBinding>
<binding name="NewBinding0" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" >
<readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
<reliableSession enabled="true" />
<security mode="None"><transport clientCredentialType="None" />
<message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="false" />
</security></binding></wsHttpBinding>

Comment: I am confused as how to mention the attribute maxReceivedMessageSize at server side.What shall be the exact position for the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Is the error occuring when the client sends a message to the server?  If so, check to make sure that in your server's config file the endpoint is referencing the binding you created:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
 bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" contract="IDBSyncContract" />
```

If you don't reference the binding you created named "NewBinding0" via the endpoint element's bindingConfiguration attribute, WCF will use the default values for WsHttpBinding - which in the case of MaxReceivedMessageSize is 65536.

**UPDATE**

Setting the MaxReceivedMessageSize value on the server side config is exactly the same as it is on the client config.  Simply set the `maxReceivedMessageSize` attribute on the `binding` element:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="NewBinding0" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"> 
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    <reliableSession enabled="true" /> 
    <security mode="None">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" /> 
      <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="false" /> 
    </security>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim,But I have mentioned the value while creating the object.I am little confused where to mention the attribute on server side.I tried it to mention on readerQuotas and Binding but to no avail.

Comment: Also Below is the server config file further details.<service behaviorConfiguration="DBSyncWcfService.Service1Behavior" name="DBSyncWcfService.DBSyncService">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" name="ABC" contract="DBSyncWcfService.IDBSyncContract" />

Comment: Is the address the client uses defined somewhere in the server's config file? If not, I'm wondering if your request from the client might be going to a default endpoint, which would be using a default WsHttpBinding, which might result in this problem.

Comment: Hi,Tim u mean to say that I need to mention the address "http://192.168.5.170/DBSyncWcfSevice/DBSyncService.svc" somewhere in base address section  <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://192.168.5.161/DBSyncWcfService" />
          </baseAddresses> or in endpoint section.

Comment: I believe so, yes (haven't had a chance to play with WCF 4.0 yet, so just going off what I've read).  The other option is to define the default binding for WsHttpBinding for your service so that is picked up by WCF - but I think the simplest would be to add "192.168.5.170/DBSyncWcfService/DBSyncService.svc" to the address attribute of your endpoint element.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I am also working on .Net 3.5.I have added the link in both baseaddress section and endpoint attribute as well.Now what changes shall I do now in config file for MaxReceivedMessageSize attribute.

Comment: You've already set the maxReceivedMessageSize attribute on the binding element, so you should be good.  Give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: I have mentioned it on Client Side not on Service Config file.

Comment: Ah..just noticed your service config file didn't have the attribute set.  I've updated my answer, but in a nutshell you set it in the config file for the server exactly the same way you set it in the client's config file.