# Any idea how to put such an object to the WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf

Good day.

I have the following question:

How to put the following object

```
[DataContract]
public class TimeItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime LocalTime { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double XPos { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double YPos { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public byte[] ScreenImage { get; set; } //Could be very huge
}
```

to the WCF service? (I write the WCF service as well, so I can customize it if I need).
It works fine, but, in case of large bytes array (ScreenImage) I get an error 400 (Bad service request).

Comment: Could you please update your question with response body? Use fiddler or similar to get it. Presume we'll see an exception message and stacktrace there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are things you can do to allow larger arrays (changing the serialization quotas; using MTOM; etc), but *ultimately* there is a limit to what you can send as a single message. It sounds like you are going to be bumping against the limit *no matter* what you do, so I would suggest looking at redesigning the API to take *fragments* of the data in separate messages, and re-combine at the server.

Comment: You mean like re-implementing [streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) regarding the transfer of large data to/fro a WCF service.  It will require you to change your data contract to a [Message Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx), using the [MessageContractAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagecontractattribute.aspx) instead of `DataContract`, [MessageHeaderAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messageheaderattribute.aspx) instead of `DataMember` on all but the large data field, and then the [MessageBodyMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagebodymemberattribute.aspx) on the byte data - which should be changed to a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx).

Please note that the streams received this way tend to return `false` on the [CanSeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek.aspx) property so be careful how you read the data from the stream.

You may also need to adjust your message size allowances on both client and server side configurations, using something similar to that [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Maybe u need to increase the size of ur wcf message size (in web config file).

check this link,
[May this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota)

Comment: @user306080 - and did u set the MaxItemInObjectGraph? 
(Link: http://blog.hill-it.be/2007/08/22/maxitemsinobjectgraph-and-keeping-references-when-serializing-in-wcf-2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `maxReceivedMessageSize` attribute of a binding definition. It will allow you to send larger requests.

```
...
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="httpBinding" 
    maxBufferPoolSize="965536"
    maxReceivedMessageSize="965536">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="965536" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
...
```