# Getting Maximumsize issue, while reading the Byte Array from WCF service to ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, azure-storage

I am reading the pdf in byte array from my WCF web service and returning it to the web application to prepare the file temporary. But somehow I am getting this exception:

```
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element
```

While reading the Byte Array from WCF service.

My binding tag in web application is as follows. 
I tried to replace the number 104857600 with 2147483647 also. But the issue is still there. 
Can somebody help? What I am missing?

```
 <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="104857600" maxBufferPoolSize="104857600" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="104857600" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="104857600"
            maxBytesPerRead="104857600" maxNameTableCharCount="104857600" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to include these same binding configurations on the WCF service host as well.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota/884248#884248) for reference.