# NSURLConnection Post body size limit issue to WCF?

Tags: iphone, wcf, http-post, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I would like to upload couple of images and a text file from iphone to WCF using **one** `NSURLConnection` Post request. So, I attached the `NSData` for the images into the body of the request. Apparently, when the Length of body exceeds 65535 bytes, the request doesn't work and won't call WCF. It does work for < 65535 bytes. How can I do this, images can easily be 50,000 bytes each...Am I doing something worng?  If not, what's the correct way of handling this? To be honest, I am not quite sure if the problem is on the iphone(client side) or WCF side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably on the WCF side in your web.config file. Please see the question [WCF - How to Increase Message Size Quota](https://stackoverflow.com/q/884235/830125) and [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/884248/830125) for more information. Basically, you need to increase the WCF buffer sizes and message size quotas, to get something like this for your `<httpBinding>`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MyBasicHttpBinding"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                maxBufferSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxDepth="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <!-- Other code here -->

</system.serviceModel>
```

You may need or want to adjust these numbers to fit your needs.

Comment: Do you have anything for REST? Here is mine. <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="StreamedRequestWebBinding" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" useDefaultWebProxy="false" hostNameComparisonMode="WeakWildcard" sendTimeout="10:15:00" openTimeout="10:15:00" receiveTimeout="10:15:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

Comment: @software2007: So you're still seeing the issue with that binding? What does the HTTP response to your request look like?

Comment: No response, WCF method doesn't even get invoked for requests> 65535 bytes.

Comment: @software2007: Ok, so if you run this in the simulator and look at the requests with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or similar, is the app even making the request? If it is, then there has to be some HTTP response, whether it's a 404, 5xx, etc. That information will help us solve the problem.