# MaxReceivedMessageSize value allowed in WCF Test Client configuration .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm getting message like this:

```
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
```

I checked on net, not able to find the portion to chage in configuration file here (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE). The file name and content is WcfTestClient.exe.config

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
 <runtime>
   <DisableMSIPeek enabled="true"/>
 </runtime>
</configuration>
```

How can I change this to get it work. Please note that, My WCF application is working fine, when I have less output character and this WCF Test client is given by .Net framework.I found this: http://tzonsoftware.blogspot.in/2009/07/changing-wcf-test-client-configuration.html. But, what would be the max size I can keep? Please help.

Comment: Right-click the service in the test client and click Configure...

Comment: What should be the max size value I can keep?

Comment: The max size is 2147483647, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564047/wcf-the-maximum-message-size-quota-for-incoming-messages-65536-has-been-exceed but I suggest you also try to figure out what a sensible value here is rather than just max it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF - How to Increase Message Size Quota](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota)

Answer (score 1):

At least in WCF Test Client 15.0.28127.55 the steps are:

1. Expand your service node and you will see a *Configuration file*
   item at the bottom.
2. Right click > *Edit with SvcConfigEditor*.
3. Go to your *Bindings* in the tree. Choose the one you want to edit.
4. Edit the *MaxReceivedMessageSize*. Or any other property.
5. Save with the menu *File* > *Save*.
6. **Close your opened tabs**, and open a new one. Otherwise the change will not work.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it helped to me. But I would add, that better to change `Config file` outside WCF Test client and restart it. 
I did right click on `Config file`, copied full path, opened config in `notepad` and added `maxReceivedMessageSize` attribute and saved config. After that `WCF Test Client` asked restarting. And only after restarting error got away.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the MaxReceivedMessagesSize directly in the web.config or you use the Microsoft Service Configuration Editor. (Visual Studio -> TOOLS -> WCF Service Configuration Editor).

In this editor you go to Bindings -> your Binding and then you can change the MaxReceivedMessagesSize and other size you want(Example: 1073741824).

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything in the window, just File and Help menus and empty editor. Even when WCF Test Client is running.