# WCF Service Increase maximum message size quota and configuration

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

This is my web.config for my WCF Service:

```
    <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  >
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="BouncyCastle.Crypto" publicKeyToken="0e99375e54769942" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.8.6.0" newVersion="1.8.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBContext" connectionString="data source=.\APPDb.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
    <!--<add name="StardocsVisionContext" connectionString="data source=C:\Program Files (x86)\Stardocs\StardocsVision\Data\StardocsVisionDb.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />-->
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I have read the instructions from here [Wcf-The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564047/wcf-the-maximum-message-size-quota-for-incoming-messages-65536-has-been-exceed) to increase the maximum message size quota. However, is that only for one service?

What happens if I have multiple services?

Also, it seems like I have to define the base address for my service. However, when I compile and install this application, what will the base address be and how can I change it?

EDIT:

I added a binding to my web.config but im still encountering the memory issues.

Comment: You put one time in `wsBinding` and then you can reuse it in multipe services (obviusly in same project) with `bindingConfiguration="wsBinding"`

Comment: Sorry can you put it in my config? I am new to wcf and im really confused on how to do that.

Comment: Relative to the part `What happens if I have multiple services?` take a look here and tell me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-specify-a-service-binding-in-configuration

Comment: I updated my web.config but im still having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple services,you just need to apply this configuration for each endpoint, as follows:

```
<protocolMapping>  
    <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="wsBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

In addition,your binding configuration uses WSHttpBinding,but your endpoint uses basichttpsbinding.You need to set their values to the same value.

[image]

Your base address is the address set by deployment on IIS.

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering. This is for the client side right? I could set this in the wcf test client. Or is this for the server?

Comment: This is the configuration of the server. I suggest you study WCF document, you will get something.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial