# WCF service in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am calling WCF service in Windows Phone 8.1, there is one service which is returning large size of data,and that is why I am getting an exception.

```
"System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException".
```

InnerException

```
"Remote server not found"
```

I am really getting stuck, what to do? I also increase timeout in "web.config"

```
openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
```

But not getting the result. If there is small number of data in result, then it is giving result. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your WCF service code and client and server endpoint configurations. With the information you provide it's pretty hard to determine what is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it can't find your WCF service. But you say for small amounts of data it does. I would try change the MaxMessageSize properties shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota)

In your web.config for your wcf service add:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" 
                 maxBufferSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                 maxArrayLength="200000000"
                 maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

to the binding

Comment: user1, thanks bro for reply, I have also added it but not getting success. Please give me suggestion.

Comment: have you included Exceptions in your service? i.e. added       `<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />` to the web.config? I would then see if there is any more detail in you exception