# System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededException

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I am facing the below error when application was hosted in the server. The application is working fine on the local box.
"The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (100000000) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element."

All the searches done resulting in solving the issue with WCF But here I am not using any WCF service.

Please help me with this.

Comment: so what is your application and what does it do? do you set a `maxReceivedMessageSize` in its config file?

Comment: I am not using any web service. I am pulling data from the Team Foundation Server. Previously it was working fine. But all of a sudden I am facing the above mentioned error.

Comment: Here, have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota

Answer (score 8):

just add this to your binding in the app.config

```js
<binding name="binding name.." maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
```

Comment: Please help me solving this. All the searches I tried are talking about WCF services. But I am not using any web services in the application.

Comment: This helped in my case, THANKS :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the service model decorations on your classes ([ServiceContract] or [DataContract])? I suggest checking in all your project references if you have System.ServiceModel reference and removing it to see if any code breaks.