# upload large image in wcf getting outofMemory exceptin

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, wcf

I am uploading image from android device to WCF service. The android phone captures 5 MB file and that file is converted to base64string and passing to WCF service. I have two problems

1. if I pass small image the image will be uploaded.
2. if I pass 2 MB file, the file size goes to 0 bytes and getting OUTOFMEMORY exception

here I tried two ways 1.multipartparser and 2.stream

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the maximum size of your buffer. If you have  access to service you need to update you config file as below:

```
 <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" 
             maxBufferSize="20000000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
```

As a good sample you can check out the link below:
[WCF - How to Increase Message Size Quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota)