# Not able to insert long text in database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, wcf, fckeditor

I have `ckeditor` in the application in asp.net application through jquery.

It's working fine at `local`. Its inserting data in database, does not matter
  whatever is the length of the text. But when I insert data on live after
  putting the build on the server.

> It is not saving the data, when I reduce, its length then it is saving the data.I am inserting this text using WCF service.

Please help in this context.

Looking forward to hear regarding the same.

Comment: you need to set the datatype as `nvarchar(max)` for the respective column on the server

Comment: where does the error surface? for example, this could be because of a column without a suitable type/width, but since you mention jQuery, it could be because you're transferring it as a query-string parameter and your url is too long (and is being rejected by the server)

Comment: maybe you need to increase the max size of the message in WCF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota

Answer (score 0):

Oracle DB accepts 4000 characters as a max length of an input string (NOT a datatype). 
i.e, you are expected to send at most 4000 chars as a value.
The solution:
if you are using ASP.NET, try to use this function after changing your column type to CLOB so that its size would be up to 4GB:

```
 Public Shared Function AssignStringToCLOB(ByVal targetString As String, ByVal myConnection As OracleConnection) As OracleLob
    Dim _tempCommand As New OracleCommand()
    _tempCommand.Connection = myConnection
    _tempCommand.Transaction = _tempCommand.Connection.BeginTransaction()
    _tempCommand.CommandText = "DECLARE A " + OracleType.Clob.ToString() + "; " + "BEGIN " + "DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(A, FALSE); " + ":LOC := A; " + "END;"
    Dim p As OracleParameter = _tempCommand.Parameters.Add("LOC", OracleType.Clob)
    p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

    _tempCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim _tempCLOB As OracleLob = CType(p.Value, OracleLob)
    If targetString <> String.Empty Then
        Dim _bytesArray As Byte() = Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(targetString)
        _tempCLOB.BeginBatch(OracleLobOpenMode.ReadWrite)
        _tempCLOB.Write(_bytesArray, 0, _bytesArray.Length)
        _tempCLOB.EndBatch()
    End If

    _tempCommand.Transaction.Commit()
    Return _tempCLOB
End Function
```

and call it after opening the connection with Oracle DB to set a value to your parameter, this should work perfectly.