# Q: How to prevent WCF NetTCP message size quota exceeded

Tags: wcf

Is there any effective ways to prevent message size quota exceeded for NetTCP service that returns an undetermined-sized collection? Example I have the following service:

```
public List<string> GetDirInfo(string path)
{
    List<string> result;

    result = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path));
    result.AddRange(new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)));

    return result;
}
```

which basically just returns a list of directories and files in that given path. At times, I will reached the message size quota, e.g. return `C:\Windows\System32`.

Without changing message size quota, what is the best way to handle or prevent this sort of service call? A few ways that I can think of:

1. Convert to `Stream` service call
2. Implement `Pagination`
3. As a prevention, always check the size of `result` prior to returning.
4. Implement Callback mechanism where service will return a series of fixed sized result back to the client.

Is there any WCF configuration where the returned message will be split into multiple packets and reconstruct back by `CLR` while confining to the message size quota.

**Edit:**

I saw several postings on similar subject matter, but it all involved in changing the message size. I **do not want** to change the default message size to minimized DOS attacks.

I want to get some advise on the best practices and how you guys are handling/implementing such a case where the returning result might exceed the message size quota.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF - How to Increase Message Size Quota](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota)

Comment: This is a *very* common configuration change which you can find simply by googling.