# How to set max limit for json when serializing a Dataset using Newtosoft JSON?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft JSON in my project. In my WCF project i am converting a Dataset that has around 1000 rows with 20 columns. When i serialize Dataset and return the json string, the string is returning empty. I found out that if i reduce the rows to 100 then i am getting the string. I believe that the length of the serialize json string has exceeded the limit. How to set a maximum size for the json string when serializing a Dataset?

Regards,
Rajagopalan.

Comment: i would like to edit my comments by saying that when i serialize 1000 records to json it is being done. the problem arises only when i deserialize the JSON string, it's returning null.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such an option to set size for json message(it would have to be for xml either). Generally increase message size, I refer you to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota).