# WCF return Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, wcf

I get the the following error when I pass a byte array (10K items), what am I missing here?

This is the Configuration of my Server. I installed all of the buffers to max value

```
 <system.serviceModel>

<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="New" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="200000000" maxBytesPerRead="200000000" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="Service">
    <endpoint address="EFCore.Contract.General.AircraftService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="EFCore.Contract.General.IAircraftService" bindingConfiguration="New" />
    <endpoint address="EFCore.Contract.Dictionaries.FlightNumService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="EFCore.Contract.Dictionaries.IFlightNumService" bindingConfiguration="New" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:45617" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
  <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior>
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
  </protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

On the clientSide I connected fromCode. All works fine. But when I call the service method and pass an array(where the count of items is greater than 5000), I get an error:

> The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request
>   Entity Too Large.

```
_binding = new BasicHttpBinding
        {
            CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0),
            OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0),
            ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0),
            SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0),
            MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
            MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
            TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
            ReaderQuotas =
            {
                MaxArrayLength = 200000000,
                MaxBytesPerRead = 200000000,
                MaxDepth = 200000000,
                MaxStringContentLength = 200000000
            }
        };endPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://91.213.233.139:45617/Servicies/AircraftService.svc");
            var channelFactoryFoo = new ChannelFactory<IAircraftService>(_binding, endPoint);
            return (IRepository<T>) channelFactoryFoo.CreateChannel();
```

Comment: C is a very different language than C#, please be careful with your tags

Answer (score 0):

use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota)  to increase message size quotas