# After added all settings in Web.config it still gives error - The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-config

After added all settings in Web.config it still gives error - The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
Following is my web.config setting.

```
<services>
      <service name="OASYS_Services.GetOasysModel"  >
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ECMSBindingConfig"
          contract="OASYS_Services.IGetOasysModel" name="ECMSBindingConfig" >
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ECMSBindingConfig"  allowCookies="false"  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" bypassProxyOnLocal="true"  >
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
              maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647"
              maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    </services>
```

Any missing content in web.config?

Comment: Check that you have increased the buffer on the client as well as indicated in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3412171/2706695

Comment: Can you provide an MVCE?