# Unable to call WCF service Operation using service reference

Tags: wcf

[image]*I have added WCF service reference to console application and trying to call service operation,I got QuotaExceededException.
I have searched for solution for this but i found i need to change binding maxlength. But it is not possible for me.I should not change service configuration.*

**Exception Message :**

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been
> exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
> property on the appropriate binding element.

[image]

**Below Is the stack Trace:**

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ThrowMaxReceivedMessageSizeExceeded()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.GetMessageBuffer()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, Exception& requestException)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at ConsoleApp2.ComponentService.IComponentService.GetPageConfiguration(String pageName, String roleCode, String processName, String wizardPageConfigGUID)
   at ConsoleApp2.ComponentService.ComponentServiceClient.GetPageConfiguration(String pageName, String roleCode, String processName, String wizardPageConfigGUID) in D:\Work\tempABC\local\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Connected Services\ComponentService\Reference.cs:line 5684
   at ConsoleApp2.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Work\tempABC\local\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs:line 13
```

**This is my Config file Content :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ABC.EUV.Component.Service.Contract.IComponentService">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://hyddmosrvi01.vertafore.com/XYZ/WebServices/ComponentService/ComponentService.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ABC.EUV.Component.Service.Contract.IComponentService"
                contract="ComponentService.IComponentService" name="ABC.EUV.Component.Service.Contract.IComponentService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Add binding `<binding name="binding name.." maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>` to your app.config

Comment: I don't have service with me.It is hosted in different location.So i can't change configuration.

Comment: When you add service reference to your project service client configuration automatically included to your config. So please share your web.config. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota

Comment: I have posted my configuration file.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the message size quotas, in the config as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ABC.EUV.Component.Service.Contract.IComponentService" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000" maxBufferSize="200000000" maxBufferPoolSize="200000000">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://hyddmosrvi01.vertafore.com/XYZ/WebServices/ComponentService/ComponentService.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ABC.EUV.Component.Service.Contract.IComponentService"
                contract="ComponentService.IComponentService" name="ABC.EUV.Component.Service.Contract.IComponentService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```